# How do I set my DNS when resolv.conf is being overwritten?

Tags: linux, debian, networking, dns, dnsmasq

Most of the info I see online says to edit `/etc/resolv.conf`, but any changes I make there just get overridden.

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- 
#     YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

It seems that 127.0.1.1 is a local instance of `dnsmasq`. The `dnsmasq` docs say to edit `/etc/resolv.conf`. I tried putting custom nameservers in `/etc/resolv.conf.d/base`, but the changes didn't show up in `/etc/resolv.conf` after running `sudo resolvconf -u`.

FYI, I don't want to change DNS on a per-connection basis, I want to set default DNS settings to use for all connections when not otherwise specified.

***UPDATE:***

I answered this question myself:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/163506/67024

I think it's the best solution since:

1. It works.
2. It requires the least amount of changes and
3. It still works in conjunction with dnsmasq's DNS cache, rather than bypassing it.

Comment: Better answer your question instead of update your question I think... will be easier to find the right answer you gave to your problem

Comment: It seems that most answers are Ubuntu-oriented, and overly complicated.  A universal solution for NetworkManager users is to simply add `dns=none` in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` (see details in my answer below).

Comment: I think this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174349/what-overwrites-etc-resolv-conf-on-every-boot) clarifies why the resolve.conf is overwritten, then you know how to configure it.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I found out that you can change the nameservers that `dnsmasq` uses by adding the following lines to `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`:

```
server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4
```

I didn't have a `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` file though, since it's installed by the dnsmasq package, but Ubuntu only comes with dnsmasq-base. I ran `sudo apt-get install dnsmasq`, then edited `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`, then `sudo service dnsmasq restart` and `sudo service network-manager restart`.

I ran `sudo tail -n 200 /var/log/syslog` to check my syslog and verify that `dnsmasq` was using the nameservers I specified:

```
Oct 21 23:00:54 mylaptop dnsmasq[8611]: using nameserver 8.8.8.8#53
Oct 21 23:00:54 mylaptop dnsmasq[8611]: using nameserver 8.8.4.4#53
```

Comment: There is a reason why this is marked as the best answer...because it is indeed! thanks very much! I would add that, after all the steps you mentioned, a network restart might be necessary for everything to work smoothly (it was for me.... `sudo service network-manager restart`)

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04 Server about half the time a cold boot would result no internet connectivity using a URL but an IP-Address would work. I spent a lot of time fruitlessly trying to fix it, gave up for months, then found this solution.  I, too,  think it is the best answer.

Comment: It's intriguing that dnsmasq has to be installed. This indeed fixed my DNS in a normal situation, but it totally broke my VPN configuration (VPN connection now fails...)

Comment: there is no such file on Centos

Comment: ubuntu 16: changes from the procedure with `dnsmasq` are not being propagated into `/etc/resolv.conf`. The consequence is, hat nslookup still uses its original defined localhost 127.0.0.1. Although I can confirm your syslogs mentioned.

Comment: I hardly know what's going on... but I go to "Edit Connections" and "IPv4 Settings" and add those 2 DNS servers and it works!!

Answer (score 306):

I believe if you want to override the DNS nameserver you merely add a line similar to this in your `base` file under `resolv.conf.d`.

#### Example

**NOTE:** Before we get started, sure the following package is installed, `apt install resolvconf`.

```
$ sudo vim /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base
```

Then put your nameserver list in like so:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Finally update `resolvconf`:

```
$ sudo resolvconf -u
```

If you take a look at the man page for `resolvconf` it describes the various files under `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/`.

```
   /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base
          File  containing  basic  resolver  information.  The lines in this 
          file are included in the resolver configuration file even when no
          interfaces are configured.

   /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head
          File to be prepended to the dynamically generated resolver 
          configuration file.  Normally this is just a comment line.

   /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail
          File to be appended to the dynamically generated resolver 
          configuration file.  To append nothing, make this  an  empty  
          file.   This file is a good place to put a resolver options line 
          if one is needed, e.g.,

              options inet6
```

Even though there's a warning at the top of the `head` file:

```
$ cat /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
```

this warning is is there so that when these files are constructed, the warning will ultimately work its way into the resulting `resolv.conf` file that these files will be used to make. So you could just as easily have added the `nameserver` lines that are described above for the `base` file, to the `head` file too.

#### References

- [Persist dns nameserver for ubuntu 14.04](http://www.netroby.com/view.php?id=3630#.U2mTfHVdUc0)
- [How do I add a DNS server via resolv.conf?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130452/how-do-i-add-a-dns-server-via-resolv-conf)

Comment: I believe you should add this line to the `base` file as the head file basically contains the header comments to tell you not to modify the file.

Comment: @xuhdev - I've changed the A to use `base` but you could've used `head` as well. See my updates for more info.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 - when I put the nameservers into `base` and run `resolvconf -u`, the nameservers were *not* put into resolv.conf - when I put the nameservers into `head`, they were

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 - Also had to comment out configuration set in `/run/resolvconf/interface/NetworkManager`

Comment: type `nslookup google.com` and the first IP in the list should be your new nameserver, if not, you did it wrong

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04: Worked if appended to `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` only, not with `base`. Confirmed with `nslookup google.com`.

Comment: At least for Debian bullseye, the documentation for files `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/*` is found in `man 8 resolvconf`.

Answer (score 90):

I am also interested in this question and I tried the solution proposed @sim.

To test it, I put

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

in `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` and

```
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

in `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`

Then I restarted the network with

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

The result is that `/etc/resolv.conf` looks like

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

and `nm-tool` states that the  dnsserver are

```
DNS:             208.67.222.222
DNS:             208.67.220.220
```

which are the ones provided by my router.
On the other hand digging an address tells that

```
;; Query time: 28 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.4.4#53(8.8.4.4)
```

If I am right, I conclude from all this that

1. only the "head" part is read by resolvonf: the "base" part is
   somehow controlled by dnsmasq
2. the dnsserver is actually forced to
   8.8.4.4 regardless of the server provided by dhcp, BUT you loose the caching provided by dnsmasq, since the request is always sent to 8.8.4.4
3. dnsmasq is still using ONLY the dnsserver provided by dhcp.

All in all, it works but I don't think it is the intended result asked for.
A more close solution I think is the following. Edit

```
sudo vim /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf
```

then add

```
supersede domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;
```

The result is the following: resolv.conf contains only 127.0.0.1, which means that dnsmasq cache  is invoked and nm-tool says

```
DNS:             8.8.8.8
```

which means that if the name searched for is not in the cache, then it is asked for at 8.8.8.8 and not at the server provided by dhcp.

Another (perhaps better) option is to use "prepend" instead of "supersede": in this way, if the name is not resolved by 8.8.8.8, then the request falls back on the other server. In fact, nm-tool says

```
DNS:             8.8.8.8    
DNS:             208.67.222.222
DNS:             208.67.220.220
```

Comment: A much better answer than hacking into the NS configs. Especially the option to prepend a server in front of the dhcp provided ones. Seems like the perfect balance of solving the problem, without creating new ones!

Comment: It's worth noting nm-tool has been replaced with nmcli

Answer (score 26):

For static IP situations, the Ubuntu Server Guide says to change the file /etc/network/interfaces, which may look like this:

```
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.3.3
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.3.1
dns-search example.com
dns-nameservers 192.168.3.45 192.168.8.10
```

You change the IPs 192.168.3.45 192.168.8.10 for the ones you want, like 8.8.8.8

https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/serverguide.pdf
Page 38

Comment: This certainly looks right but how do I now regenerate resolv.conf?!

Comment: @JoelBerger `ifdown eth0; ifup eth0`.

Comment: no /etc/network/interfaces on Centos

Comment: quick question, how many name server can we put on ?

Answer (score 21):

1. Search ' Network Connection'
2. Open it

   [image]
3. Then select either WiFi or Ethernet, or whatever you are using, and click on edit. You'll get this:

   [image]
4. Select ipv4 in tabs
5. Select addresses only in method
6. Enter your DNS name below, and save it
7. You're done

Comment: I'd have to do this for each network connection though. In the past you could change the default for all connections, which is what I was looking to do here.

Comment: I love you! this UI setting saved my ass from sudo and vim mess :'(

Comment: Using Mint (on Ubuntu 14.04) - but seen this with KDE, too - for some reason, setting DNS servers in the GUI Network Manager doesn't affect the DNS settings used in a terminal

Comment: Best answer imho. On Ubuntu 14.04 I got 2 external IP-addresses for DNS that wouldn't recognise clients inside my home network. Leaving Method on 'Automatic (DHCP)' for the wired connection _added_ my router's IP-address to the existing list. For the wireless connection over wlan0, that didn't work, but Method on 'Automatic (DHCP) addresses only' _replaced_ the external addresses with my router IP and then that worked too. Apply changes with `sudo service network-manager restart`, wait a bit, verify with `nmcli d list | grep 'DNS\|IP-IFACE'`. And ping your internal client by name.

Comment: this is the correct answer

Answer (score 19):

A quick and dirty workaround that wasn't mentioned yet is setting the immutable flag on the `resolv.conf` file right after editing it.

```
$ sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

Add this and save:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Then:

```
$ sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

That should do the trick. I do this on my system too.

Comment: Anytime your solution involves chattr, it's not really a solution.

Comment: this is what I do on systems where I need to temporarily change the DNS for some reason and don't want to modify the configuration. As a permanent solution I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: "quick and dirty workaround"

Comment: This isn't dirty. Programs that destroy local configuration because they think they know better are dirty.

Comment: How do I find out which program is changing my resolv.conf file???

Comment: There is usually a comment in the resolv.conf file such as "# generated by". The usual suspects are NetworkManager and systemd-resolved.

Answer (score 14):

My issue was a bit different, I wanted to override my routers DNS servers. I found this link from Ubuntu: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OverrideDNSServers

It says:
If you would like to override the DNS settings provided to you by a DHCP server, open

```
/etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf
```

and add the following line:

```
supersede domain-name-servers <dns_ip_address1>,<dns_ip_address2>;
```

replacing `<dns_ip_address*>` items with the proper content.

Comment: This is the answer that solved my issue.

Comment: Perfect. Just adding that you should sudo service networking restart to enable the changes.

Comment: What if we don't have that `dhcp3` folder? I have Xubuntu 17.10, has it moved to `/etc/dhcp` simply?

Comment: @PlasmaBinturong in my case it was `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` on latest Debian and Ubuntu versions.

Answer (score 5):

Try adding `dns-nameservers XXX.XXX.XXX.X` into your `/etc/networking/interfaces` file.

Comment: Leave a comment when you downvote, please. This is the method given in the [manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/serverguide.pdf), page 38.

Comment: The unmentioned manual shows all IPs on one line. This answer seems to suggest adding a line. And why is the last number only one X wide? I think it mostly was the extremely informal and uncertain short chat-style writing that garnered the downvotes, @Zook.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I'm missing something, but according to the config instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html all you do is update the following. I am not running a proxy - just a machine behind a firewall and local DNS (example shows Googles, but set it to whatever you need).

```
nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

**Default:**

```
# This file...
# and how to activate...

# The loopback...
auto local
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface 
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

**UPDATED:**

```
# This file...
# and how to activate...

# The loopback...
auto local
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface 
#iface eth0 inet dhcp
iface eth0 inet static
address x.x.x.x
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway x.x.x.x

#nameservers
# you may not need dns-search
# I use it because I'm running this on a Windows network 
# so its useful to have
# dns-search x.y 
dns-nameservers 4.4.4.4 8.8.8.8
```

Reboot, if you can.

Answer (score 3):

There are **two** methods

#### Method 1

The DNS server to use can be changed by updating `head` file in under `resolv.conf.d`

```
$ echo 'nameserver 1.1.1.1' | sudo tee /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base
```

and then run

```
$ sudo resolvconf -u
```

The above will generate a generic `resolv.conf` file in the `/etc` directory. All your resolve requests will be sent to the above said nameserver. *Solved.*

However there are implications to this. When using `resolvconf` to directly query `1.1.1.1` for address resolutions, the power of caching provided by dnsmasq is gone. Every request will go to `1.1.1.1`

#### Method 2

If you don't want above to happen and use dnsmasq for DNS resolutions refer [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/163506/67024) answer. The answer is simply described here.

Add the following content in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` file.

> server=1.1.1.1

Then restart the dnsmasq service

```
$ sudo systemctl restart dnsmasq.service
```

Things will work fine. *Solved.*

Answer (score 2):

Some of the answers here work just fine. However I wasn't happy with the fact I have to manually go through configuration files just to set the "proper" `DNS` which **I already** am receiving over `DHCP` with `NetworkManager`.

I did a little digging and noticed that the `/etc/resolv.conf` file is actually a link and it's pointing to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`. After some experimenting it appears that `/run/systemd/resolve/` directory contains another file named `resolv.conf` which already contains the settings you've received via `DHCP`. So, instead of having to manually overwrite/create configuration files in `/etc/`, you can simply re-link `/etc/resolv.conf` to point to the `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` file and all should be just fine:

```
# sudo ln -sf /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

You should now be able to edit the settings even from the Network Manager in Gnome. :)

Not sure if this will work on older ubuntu's but it does on Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: when we run `systemd-resolve --flush-cache` the original linked file is severed apparently, the answer above restore the original functionality

Answer (score 2):

*NB : Like most answers, this one assumes the use of NetworkManager.  However unlike most other answers, it doesn't assume the use of `resolvconf`, `dhclient` or anything else — beware that they may take over, though (see update).*

Given the number of views of this question it's quite incredible that this **8 characters** solution hasn't been posted yet : according to `man NetworkManager.conf`,

> dns: […] none: NetworkManager will not modify resolv.conf. This implies rc-manager unmanaged

Therefore add

```
dns=none
```

in the `[main]` section of `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` then restart NetworkManager and it won't modify `/etc/resolv.conf` anymore.

Note that setting `rc-manager=unmanaged` should be equivalent to `dns=none`, and that setting `rc-manager=symlink` along with having `/etc/resolv.conf` as a symbolic link may be a better idea (read above-mentioned manpage).

### Update :

After NetworkManager stopped overwriting `/etc/resolv.conf`, I figured `dhcpcd` was already replacing `/etc/resolv.conf` by a useless empty file at boot.  The manpage of `dhcpcd.conf` helped, it suffices to add

```
nohook resolv.conf
```

in your `dhcpcd.conf` (mine is in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`).

Comment: This is a very good answer.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT MAY 6,2016**

I've written a script to update all settings for system connections in the `/etc/Network-Manager/system-connections/` directory. The GUI that you use to edit individual connections, edits a particular file in that directory. The script updates all of the files - it just searches for those who don't have dns set with grep and sets it with awk.

Since accessing those files requires `sudo` access, run this script with `sudo` and then - restart network manager

```
#!/bin/bash
# Author: Serg Kolo
# Date: May 6, 2015
# Description: this script checks all settings for connections in 
# /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ , and if there's no custom
# dns set , this script sets it;
# NOTE: run sudo service network-manager restart after running this script

set -x

for file in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/* ; do
        grep 'dns=208.67.220.220;' "$file"  || ( awk '{print;if ($1=="[ipv4]"){getline; print "method=auto\ndns=208.67.220.
220;\nignore-auto-dns=true"}}' "$file" > .tmpfile && ( cat .tmpfile > "$file") )
done
```

Script in action:

[image]

**ORIGINAL POST**
Some users here pointed out that DNS is somehow controlled by `dnsmasq`. That is indeed true. I've faced a somewhat smaller issue, where no matter how I changed `head` or `body` in `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d` , my computer couldn't actually access interned by domain name - only working with IP addresses.

What I did is to edit the `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` file.  Originally, it said `dns=dnsmasq` but I changed it to: `dns=208.67.222.222`.  Although this way, `nm-tool` doesn't mention 208.67.222.222, I still was able to use domain names, not just IP addresses.

Here's how my `NetworkManager.conf` file looks like now:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
#dns=dnsmasq
dns=208.67.222.222

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

**NOTE:** For more details on my problem and this solution, refer to my post on [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/542922/able-to-access-web-by-ip-but-not-by-dns-name).

#### UPDATE #1

Having returned home from the university today, I discovered that I couldn't connect to my home WiFi. I've read-up a little on `man NetworkManager.conf` and it turns out that `dns=` in `[main]` is actually a line for plug-ins, so line `dns=dnsmasq` is actually adding the dnsmasq plugin to the NetworkManager, apparently.

So my solution still worked, just not as I had expected. Here's excerpt from the man page:

> ```
> dns=plugin1,plugin2, ... List DNS plugin names separated by ','.
> ```
>
> DNS plugins are used to provide local caching nameserver functionality
>   (which speeds up DNS queries) and to push DNS data to applications
>   that use it.

So by setting `dns=208.67.222.222` I may have, basically, prevented NetworkManager from using that plugin, which would otherwise used the local DNS server (which apparently doesn't work).

Answer (score 1):

That's because a particular installed application is managing this file.
You can either uninstall that application or set your desired options directly through that application.

On my case (Linux centos7 minimal server) having same situation I was getting `# Generated by NetworkManager` at top of `resolv.conf` file so the best way I could change this option was using

### `nmtui`

command. You can edit nameservers in this tool and when you change options of networkmanager from this utility they will be automatically applied to `/etc/resolv.conf` after reboot. [Here you can find more information](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Networking_Config_Using_nmtui.html).

Comment: Thanks for this.

The "more information" link has gone stale, but searching on RedHat's site finds similar documentation:
https://access.redhat.com/search/?q=nmtui

Answer (score 1):

Nothing at all on the Internet helped me, because NordVPN's CLI utility kept overwriting `/etc/resolv.conf` every time I connected and disocnnected from the VPN. It even overrode `chattr +i`, which was super annoying!!

What worked for me was *completely disabling resolvconf*!

Edit `/etc/resolvconf.conf` and make this the only entry:

```
resolv_conf=NO
```

This specifically disables `resolvconf`, meaning your `/etc/resolv.conf` will never be changed by it. Then go ahead and `sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf` for good measure.

Tested on Arch Linux.

Answer (score 1):

On Centos 7, using NetworkManager, the cleanest, persisent, working solution that I've been able to find is to create a NetworkManager script that uses nmcli to set the values I want.

e.g.

Create `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/mydns.sh` with permissions 755 and the following contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

if [ $1 == "enp0s11" -a $2 == "up" ]
then
        echo "Setting my DNS ($1 is $2)" | logger

        # disable default DNS
        nmcli device mod enp0s11 ipv4.ignore-auto-dns yes

        # Substitute our own DNS, in the desired order
        nmcli device mod enp0s11 ipv4.dns "10.0.1.101 10.0.1.1"
fi
```

And to test, without rebooting:

```
systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

YMMV, but this is the only way I've found that allows my /etc/resolv.conf to 'survive' a reboot without being overwritten with values I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to change DNS:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

If issues come up, install `nano`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install nano -y
```

then ..

1. find this: `dns-nameservers`
2. if you don't find it just type it in there
3. I did mine like this:  `dns-nameservers 199.85.126.10 199.85.127.10`

I hope this is the best way, I did it like this on a VPS by the way.

Answer (score 0):

on root:

1. comment `dns=dnsmasq` on `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`
2. add `supersede domain-name-servers 4.2.2.1,4.2.2.3,4.2.2.5,4.2.2.4,4.2.2.1,4.2.2.2;` at the end of `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`
3. `sudo service network-manager restart`

The following makes the changes shown above:

```
$ sudo sed -i 's/dns\x3Ddnsmasq/\x23dns\x3Ddnsmasq/' \
   /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

$ echo 'supersede domain-name-servers 4.2.2.1,4.2.2.3,4.2.2.5,4.2.2.4,4.2.2.1,4.2.2.2;' | \
   sudo tee --append /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf

$ sudo service network-manager restart
```

Wait 7/10 seconds to finish the restart process, check your config with
"nslookup nist.gov". Works well on Ubuntu LTS 14.04.