# What overwrites /etc/resolv.conf on every boot?

Tags: networking, dhcp, busybox, resolv.conf, udhcpc

I was given the files for a mini `linux`, that boots directly into `firefox`. It works for all it should be doing, only that I do not get an internet connection.

We have 3 DNS servers in the network, which all work. I can ping them, too. But when trying to `ping google.de` or `wget google.de` I get a `bad address` error.

`nslookup google.de` works for some reason.

I tracked the issue down to my `resolv.conf` on the booted system not having the same contents as the `resolv.conf` that I put into the `.iso` file.

I tried understanding all the factors that go into creating and modifying `resolv.conf`. I'm not quite sure I got it all, but I definitely didn't find my solution there.

So as a last ditch effort, I tried making the `resolv.conf` file immutable using

```
:~# chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

When rebuilding and booting again to my surprise my file was renamed to `resolv.conf~` and in its place was the same standard file that has been haunting me.

The file contents make me believe it gets the information from the network itself. When starting the `.iso` in Virtualbox without internet access, my file is being kept as it is.

I tried changing `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` to not get the information from the net, by deleting `domain-name-server` and `domain-name-search` from the `request` part of the file.

Didn't work unfortunately.

I don't have the NetworkManager installed. The iso is based on Ubuntu 14.04.

There is probably vital information missing. I'm happy to provide it.

UPDATE:

I think I found the file that clears `resolv.conf`.

It seems to be `/usr/share/udhcpc/default.script`

```
#!/bin/sh

# udhcpc script edited by Tim Riker <Tim@Rikers.org>

[ -z "$1" ] && echo "Error: should be called from udhcpc" && exit 1

RESOLV_CONF="/etc/resolv.conf"
[ - n "$broadcast" ] && BROADCAST="broadcast $broadcast"
[ -n "$subnet" ] && NETMASK="netmask $subnet"

case "$1" in
    deconfig)
        /bin/ifconfig $interface 0.0.0.0
        for i in /etc/ipdown.d/*; do
            [ -e $i ] && . $i $interface
        done
        ;;

    renew|bound)
        /bin/ifconfig $interface $ip $BROADCAST $NETMASK

        if [ -n "$router" ] ; then
            echo "deleting routers"
            while route del default gw 0.0.0.0 dev $interface ; do
                :
            done

            metric=0
            for i in $router ; do
                route add default gw $i dev $interface metric $((metric++))
            done
        fi

        echo -n > $RESOLV_CONF # Start ----------------  
        [ -n "$domain" ] && echo search $domain >> $RESOLV_CONF
        for i in $dns ; do
            echo adding dns $i
            echo nameserver $i >> $RESOLV_CONF
        done
        for i in /etc/ipup.d/*; do
            [ -e $i ] && . $i $interface $ip $dns 
        done # End ------------------
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

It's part of the `udhcpc` program. A tiny dhcp client, that is part of `busybox`

Will investigate further.

---

UPDATE2 AND SOLUTION:

I commented the part out (#Start to #End), that seemingly overwrites the `/etc/resolv.conf` file and sure enough. That was the culprit. So an obscure script caused all this trouble.

I changed the question to reflect, what actually needed to be known to solve my problem, so it would be easier to find for people with the same problem and so I could accept an answer.

Thanks for the help here in figuring things out.

Comment: Setting the immutable flag on resolv.conf doesn't work as you expected as the file was not changed. The directory entry in /etc was changed when the file was renamed. You'd have to set /etc to be immutable - something you really don't want to do.

Comment: @DougO'Neal I see. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

1. You shouldn't manually update your `resolv.conf`, because all changes will be overwritten by data that your local DHCP server provides. If you want it to be static, run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` and answer "no" to dynamic updates. If you want to add new entries there, edit `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` and run `sudo resolvconf -u`, it will append your entries and DHCP server's entries.
2. Try to edit your `/etc/network/interfaces` and add your entries there, like

   ```
    auto eth0 
    iface eth0 inet dhcp 
    dns-search google.com 
    dns-nameservers dnsserverip
   ```

and then restart `/etc/init.d/networking restart` or `sudo ifdown -a` and `sudo ifup -a`

3. Your system uses [udhcp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udhcpc) which is a very small DHCP client program. The udhcp client negotiates a lease with the DHCP server and notifies
   a set of scripts when a leases is obtained or lost. You can read about it's usage [here](http://web.mit.edu/jhawk/mnt/spo/merakidev/src/openwrt-meraki/openwrt/build_mips/busybox-1.1.0/networking/udhcp/README.udhcpc) or just edit this script (as you did).

Comment: I did add the entries into the `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` and ran `resolvconf -u`. It didn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried to run sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf? After running resolvconf -u, your entries wasn't in result file? How did you add them, like "nameserver 127.0.0.1" or "search google.com"?

Comment: I did run `dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf`. The entries were not in there. And I have entries with both `nameserver ip` and `search domain`.

Comment: No, running `dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` won't add entries, but you can disable automatic updates. If you disable updates, you can edit resolv.conf manually and it shouldn't be overwritten.

Comment: My bad for phrasing it so clumsily, I was answering your comment sentence by sentence. After running `resolvconf -u` the entries were not added.

Comment: Edited my answer, try `/etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: I already thought of that, too. Didn't work unfortunately. I have the feeling, that there is something simple, that my predecessor removed or configured, which I don't know about, since I'm not fit with networking under Linux.

Comment: I found the particular problem I had, but all your suggestions are valid ways of solving it, too. Could you add my solution in the question to your answer, so it's all in one place and I can accept yours instead of adding my own?

Comment: I edited my answer and added some info about udhcp.

Answer (score 8):

**`Ubuntu 16.04`**
If the network interfaces for your server instance is controlled by DHCP, the dhclient program will overwrite your `/etc/resolv.conf` file whenever the networking service is restarted.

You can fix the issue by editing the `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` file and adding “supersede” statements for **domain-name**, **domain-search** and **domain-name-servers** as follows:

```
supersede domain-name "local.com";
supersede domain-search "local.com";
supersede domain-name-servers 192.168.56.103;
```

In this particular case the name server is located at "192.168.56.103" and the domain name is "local.com"

Note that each line is terminated by a semi-colon and the domain name is enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work on Ubuntu 18.04. After rebooting, `/etc/resolv.conf` was overwritten with 127.0.0.53.

Comment: May be you can try this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031279/18-04-bionic-beaver-enforce-static-etc-resolv-conf/1031314#1031314

Comment: Also check if you are running `dnsmasq`

Comment: In case you don't want to overwrite but just add yours before, you can use prepend instead of supersede

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this too. Commenting out `domain-name-server` didn't fix it for me either.

Also, I'm not using `resolvconf`, just plain `/etc/resolv.conf`.

I didn't try using `chattr +i` to lock down `resolv.conf` because it seems too hacky. Also, I want Puppet to be able to modify `resolv.conf` when necessary.

The [best solution](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/dhclient-etcresolvconf-hooks/) I found overrides the default behavior of `dhclient` using its documented hooks.

Create a new file at `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/nodnsupdate` with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
make_resolv_conf() {
    :
}
```

Then make the file executable:

```
chmod +x /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/nodnsupdate
```

Now when dhclient runs -- either on reboot or when you manually run `sudo ifdown -a ; sudo ifup -a` -- it loads this script `nodnsupdate`. This script overrides an internal function called `make_resolv_conf()` that would normally overwrite `resolv.conf` and instead does nothing.

This worked for me on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Didn't work on Ubuntu 18.04 :( `/etc/resolv.conf` was overwritten after reboot.

Answer (score 2):

In Azure VMs `/etc/resolv.conf` is not directly editable.

Try adding the DNS entries in your network configuration files `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` and so on like below:

```
DOMAIN=example.com
DNS1=10.*.*.*
DNS2=10.*.*.*
DNS3=10.*.*.*
```

and restart the network service after saving the files. you will see the configuration will then be added into the resolve.conf as well.

Answer (score 1):

My ubuntu 18.04 from OVH did not come with the `/etc/network/interface` file. It uses netplan to manage the ips and nameservers. File: `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`

```
# This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
# to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
# network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    ethernets:
        ens3:
            dhcp4: true
            match:
                macaddress: fa:16:3e:d8:f7:7b
            set-name: ens3
    version: 2
```

So I did as it said and created the File:  `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg`

```
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    ethernets:
        ens3:
            dhcp4: true
            match:
                macaddress: fa:16:3e:d8:f7:7b
            set-name: ens3
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                  - 1.1.1.1
                  - 1.0.0.1
                search: [mydomain.com]
    version: 2
```

I then applied the settings with `netplan apply` , rebooted and the old settings still came back. I then checked with `ls -la /etc/resolv.conf` and noticed it was soft-linked to:

`/etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`.

So I deleted the file, and made a new one.

```
rm -f /etc/resolv.conf  
{ echo "nameserver 1.1.1.1";
echo "nameserver 1.0.0.1;
echo "search mydomain.com"; } >  /etc/resolv.conf
chattr +i  /etc/resolv.conf
reboot
```

Everything works on reboot and my file is still intact and not linked. Just don't `chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf` if it soft-linked. Remove it first.

Answer (score 0):

To make the DNS related changes in `resolv.conf` permanent, you need to change the DHCP configuration file named `dhclient.conf`. You can find the file in  `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`.

Open the file for editing (don't forget to use sudo). You’ll see lines like these:

```
#supersede domain-name "fugue.com home.vix.com";
#prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
```

Remove the preceding “#” and use the domain-name and/or domain-name-servers which you want. Save it. Now the DNS related changes will be permanent (i.e. inside `resolv.conf` file).

Credits goes to: https://itsfoss.com/resolvconf-permanent-ubuntu/

Comment: This answer had already been given [2 years earlier](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/273810/29324).

Comment: @DanDascalescu Not really. The main answer says you should add new lines to the file, while my answer says you should just uncomment these two lines. Also, the lines are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

I am not using systemd-resolved, just dhcpcd on an OVH VM running Arch Linux.

On reboot I always got a new resolv.conf with "domain openstacklocal" and the OVH DNS server.  Commenting-out the options for domain_name_servers and domain_search in /etc/dhcpcd.conf did not help.

I finally got it to stop overwriting my resolv.conf by putting the line "nohook resolv.conf" into my /etc/dhcpcd.conf file.  I found this from reading "man dhcpcd.conf".

Answer (score -1):

go to this directory:

```
  cd /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d
```

Open the file named head and put the DNS IPs or names in there.
Open the file named tail and put the domain in there.
Reboot.

Comment: That directory doesn't exist by default on Ubuntu 18.04. Do you need to install a service that creates it?

Answer (score -1):

Use the below command to prevent the `resolv.conf` or any file from overwriting after reboot:

```
chattr -V +i filename e.g chattr -V +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

To revert back the change use the below command:

```
chattr -i filename - to re-enable insert to the file
```

`chattr` (Change Attribute) is a command line Linux utility that is used to set/unset certain attributes to a file in Linux system to secure accidental deletion or modification of important files and folders, even though you are logged in as a root user.

Comment: I believe that the user in the question actually tried `chattr`, but obverved that this had no effect.

Comment: This will work for sure , The option user tried is for editing the file not for making it immutable

Comment: Please run the command with sudo chattr -V +i filename e.g sudo chattr -V +i /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: The simple trick is to remove /etc/resolv.conf first. Then remake it with your own name servers and search domain. Then ```chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf```