# How to make name server address permanent in /etc/resolv.conf even after system reboot?

Tags: etc, resolv.conf

I changed nameserver in `/etc/resolv.conf` and after a system reboot it resets the nameserver back to what it was.

I am using linux mint 19 (Cinnamon).

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

This is my file before i reboot my system and after reboot the nameserver changes.

Comment: `/etc/resolv.conf` maybe generated from other files. Which distro and version are you using?

Comment: Please add the contents of your `/etc/resolv.conf` to your question. (Format it as code by selecting it and choosing the `{}` button from the editing menu.) Obfuscate if you must must make sure you tell us what you've redacted.

Comment: i am using linux mint 19 cinnamon

Comment: Please [paste text not images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text?cb=1).

Comment: You should be able to make it permanent via NetworkManager applet on Cinnamon (sorry I don't use it so have no idea), or your System settings in Mint. Alternatively do it via editing files, as per https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration with addition of "dns-addresses 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4" (or your preferred addresses to `/etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: You might not want to make it permanent.

Comment: **Please format your text**. Like I've already explained, select the block and use the `{}` button to mark it as a code block.

Answer (score 3):

in Ubuntu 18 and I suppose in Mint 19 too, there is this new shit called "netplan".

Under **/etc/netplan/** you 'll find a .yaml file that looks like this.

```
    # Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  nameservers:
    addresses: [8.8.8.8]
```

Ente your DNS IP there and after closing it, make it permanent with `sudo netplan apply`

Alternatively you just change it in your settings (network manager GUI)

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174349/what-overwrites-etc-resolv-conf-on-every-boot)

The link says that you "shouldn't manually update your resolv.conf, because all changes will be overwritten by data that your local DHCP server provides."

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to make it permanent via NetworkManager applet on Cinnamon (*sorry I don't use it so have no idea*), or your System Settings in Mint.

Alternatively do it via editing files, as per https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration with the addition of

```
"dns-addresses 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4"
```

(*for google DNS; change to your preferred DNS addresses*) in

```
/etc/network/interfaces
```