# How to fix OpenVPN DNS leak

Tags: dns, openvpn, resolv.conf, resolvconf

I just subscribed to a VPN provider.

I have Xubuntu 17.10, openvpn 2.4.3. After launching the openvpn command I check the IP (fine) and performed a simple [DNS leak test](https://www.dnsleaktest.com): not fine, it shows my Internet Service Provider!

#### How to fix this DNS leak?

I have one preliminary interrogation:

- is it "fixable" on my side? Or is the remote server wrongly configured?

On my side, I tried changing some values in the .ovpn config file for openvpn:

1. Originally there were already these lines, that are expected to work, but nope:

   ```
   script-security 2
   up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
   down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
   ```
2. I changed them according to this [reddit answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/VPN/comments/5yc085/fix_dns_leaks_in_linux/deoyltt/) (explicitly specifying DNS addresses):

   ```
   dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222
   dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220
   dhcp-option DNS 8.26.56.26
   up "/etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf foreign_option_1='dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222' foreign_option_2='dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220' foreign_option_3='dhcp-option DNS 8.26.56.26'"
   down "/etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf foreign_option_1='dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222' foreign_option_2='dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220' foreign_option_3='dhcp-option DNS 8.26.56.26'"
   ```

   Doing that seems to do the job, as the content of `/etc/resolvconf` gets updated by the up/down scripts:

   ```
   # Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
   #     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
   # 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
   # run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

   nameserver 208.67.222.222
   nameserver 208.67.220.220
   nameserver 8.26.56.26
   search lan
   ```

   but DNSleaktest still showing my ISP.
3. So then I [learned](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/OpenVPN#Update_systemd-resolved_script) the existence of the ubuntu package `openvpn-systemd-resolved` which provides a script similar to `update-resolve-conf` but makes it work with systemd (here I have no idea what processes use this: network-manager? openvpn?). I installed the package and *replaced* the script name in my .ovpn file:

   ```
   up "/etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved ..."
   down "..."
   down-pre
   ```

   Still no luck. **[While writing this I just figured out the solution, see [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/434917/152329) below]**
4. Then I played a lot with the `/etc/resolv.conf` file. Normally it should not be changed, so I put my DNS servers addresses into `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base`, but issuing `resolvconf -u` did not appear to work.
5. Chatted with a support person from the VPN company, no solution.
6. I tried various solutions like this [one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128223), and subsequent unaccepted answers:

   - installing `dnsmasq` and putting `server=...` into `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`;
   - putting a "supersede" line in the `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` ([details](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/154538));
   - the `chattr`-based [hack](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/154926).
7. I forgot the other things I tried, then I thought, stackexchange will save me from my misery, and it miraculously did, just by the power of formulating a question.

#### [Edit 1: Not solved! Actually my first answer is not the reason it works]

I noticed it after more checking. I can remove the `systemd-update-resolved` lines and it still works, but only on certain conditions:

When the `openvpn` *service* is running, I get DNS leaks.
If I stop it, and then restart only the service for my client:

```
sudo service openvpn stop
sudo service openvpn@client start
```

then it works.

Sorry, I suppose I haven't check the openvpn manual thoroughly, but **why is that**? Isn't it a security leak? Especially because the openvpn service is activated automatically after installation from apt. **How to make the change permanent?** (I tried `sudo systemctl disable openvpn`, but at next startup I still had the same problem).

#### [Edit 2: routing tables]

Once I stopped `openvpn` and started `openvpn@client`, I don't have DNS leaks and the output of `route -n` is:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         91.240.65.1     128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eno1
91.240.64.17    192.168.1.254   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eno1
91.240.65.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 tun0
128.0.0.0       91.240.65.1     128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eno1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eno1
```

After a `sudo service openvpn restart`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         91.240.66.1     128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eno1
91.240.64.16    192.168.1.254   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eno1
91.240.66.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 tun0
128.0.0.0       91.240.66.1     128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eno1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eno1
```

Not working anymore, I get DNS leaks in both cases. I tried installing the package `openresolv` (which replaces resolvconf), and it seems to work. Here is the new routing table:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         91.240.66.161   128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eno1
91.240.64.15    192.168.1.254   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eno1
91.240.66.160   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 tun0
128.0.0.0       91.240.66.161   128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eno1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eno1
```

Comment: Please add your routing table *while* you have the VPN active.

Comment: Just did! But damned***, I can't make it work anymore, I get DNS leaks even when stopping the openvpn service!

Comment: No changes in routing. Are you setting up a client or a server?

Comment: Yes I saw no changes. I'm setting up a client.

Comment: Basically nothing works, lastly `openresolv` neither. What services should I restart after each config edit? network-manager? openvpn? Is my browser caching some data?

Comment: I uninstalled openresolv. I think I have some hints about `systemd-resolved`. It uses a file in `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` (not the one symlinked from `/etc/resolv.conf`) where the first "nameserver" is my router... It gets overwritten when I change it, so I need to find out how to configure it.

Comment: Seems like there is simply a problem with systemd-resolved: <https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6076>... It is really really sad!

Comment: you can always do  `systemctl disable systemd-resolved`

Comment: Yes indeed, but then I need to use dnsmasq for example. I just found that `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` seems to be the config file, and that `man resolved.conf` is the corresponding documentation.

Comment: You should need to check if your VPN working properly or not, here you can check https://www.vpninsights.com/ip-leak-test

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this DNS leak issue on Ubuntu 17.10 and now 18.04 LTS.  It must have started when I updated from 16.10 a while back and I never thought to check until now, by accident.  None of the above (and other things I found and tried) helped, until I ran into this URL below, reading all the way through the bug report.  The comment on adding a dns-priority line worked for me.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/network-manager/+bug/1624317  look at comment #103.

Look for your installed NetworkManager VPN connections (the '`$`' is just my system prompt, to show you're at the command line in a terminal window):

```
$ ls -la /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*
```

Then choose the one you want to fix and run this command on it (or you can just edit the config file manually, as this command just adds a dns-priority entry under section ipv4):

```
$ sudo nmcli connection modify <vpn-connection-name> ipv4.dns-priority -42
```

And restart:

```
$ sudo service network-manager restart
```

Note that at least for me, putting it in the OpenVPN .ovpn config file that came from my VPN (ProtonVPN) did not work.  For some reason it did not make it into the NetworkManager config when it was installed using the GUI dialog.  Only by updating the config after it was installed, and then restarting NetworkManager, did it work.  And you need to do this for each installed VPN config you want to use.

Comment: This works, but actually NOT really as desired. I monitor both my physical interface and `tun0`, DNS query for every domain actually gets sent, thus can be observed from both interfaces.

Comment: want to confirm that this also worked for 20.04 LTS version (after upgrading from 19.04 -> 19.10 -> 20.04)

Comment: Did not work for me on Debian Buster

Answer (score 8):

Sooo the answer is to carefully follow the always-on-point instructions from the ArchLinux wiki:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/OpenVPN#Update_systemd-resolved_script

and to **append** the corresponding lines.

So, in two steps:

```
sudo apt install openvpn-systemd-resolved
```

and **append** the following lines to your .ovpn file:

```
script-security 2
dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222
dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220
dhcp-option DNS 8.26.56.26
up /etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved
down /etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved
```

If that's not clear, your file should now contain *two* lines "up" and *two* lines "down":

```
# old lines
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
# new lines
script-security 2
dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222
dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220
dhcp-option DNS 8.26.56.26
up /etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved
down /etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved
```

#### [Edit 1: Actually NOPE, this wasn't the reason it worked]

See **Edit 1** in my question.

#### [Edit 2: I think I got it right this time]

This issue of weird `systemd-resolved.service` behavior is referenced [here](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/7182).

It seems that the option to put in the client config file is the following:

```
dhcp-option DOMAIN-ROUTE .
```

which apparently routes all DNS through the selected connection...

Comment: However, when the computer goes out of sleep, I have to restart the openvpn service and then it's leaking again...

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug due to Ubuntu switching to systemd-resolve before the network-manager-openvpn package was updated to be aware of systemd-resolve. Ubuntu 18.10 seems to have resolved this with network-manager 1.12.2-0ubuntu5. More information here: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/NetworkManager-openvpn/issues/10.

Until that's released, @Bob Willan's answer worked for me.

Comment: Tested in 18.10 with NetworkManager and works! Hopefully they will fix this in the next LTS release.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this issue discussion. Too bad they aren't providing the fix for ubuntu 18.04, but at least @bobwillan's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/470940/152329) indeed worked.

Answer (score 2):

I was running into the DNS-LeakProblem also. 
The modification of my ovpn file didn't help. Reason was a missing package. OpenVPN didn't warn me about that.

```
    script-security 2
    up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
    down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

Having a look into the script `cat /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf` i was able to see that it calls another programm at `/sbin/resolvconf`.
Doing an `ls /sbin/resolvconf` showed me that i was missing that file. A quick search brought me to [the missing package.](https://packages.debian.org/buster/resolvconf)

After installing it with `apt install openresolv` the modifications in my ovpn script took effect.

Comment: yup, that did it for me, thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by adding these lines to my OpenVPN config file :

> script-security 2
>
> up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
>
> down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf

from @ [How To Fix OpenVPN DNS Leak in Linux](http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2015/09/how-to-fix-openvpn-dns-leak-in-linux.html)

And for Windows users (OpenVPN +2.3.9) :

> block-outside-dns

Answer (score 0):

if - like me - you dont have the `resolvconf` package installed and dont want to, you can use the script below to update the `resolv.conf` file.

```
#!/bin/bash

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# EN: Update resolv.conf to use the DNS defined by the VPN
# PT: Atualiza os DNS do resolv.conf para usar os definidos pela VPN
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Get DNS defined by the VPN service
# Exit with error if the DNS array is empty
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function getVpnDns() {
    for frgn_optn in ${!foreign_option_*} ; do
        for fo in "${!frgn_optn}" ; do
            DNSARRAY+=( $(echo $fo | awk '/dhcp-option DNS/{print $3}') )
        done
    done
    [ -z "$DNSARRAY" ] && exit 1
}

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Write DNS to resolv.conf
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function writeResolvConf() {
    getVpnDns
    for DNS in ${DNSARRAY[@]} ; do
        echo "nameserver $DNS"
    done | tee /etc/resolv.conf
}

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Switch between resolv.conf configs on 'up' and 'down' events
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

case "$script_type" in
    up)
        mv -v /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.rag && writeResolvConf
    ;;
    down)
        mv -fv /etc/resolv.conf.rag /etc/resolv.conf
    ;;
esac
```