# DHCP DNS and Domain resolution NetworkManager

Tags: debian, dns, dhcp, dhclient, bind9

My environment is following, all cabled with gigalan, all latest Debian 9, vm with virtualbox on 2 different physical hosts.

- A mikrotik internet router which acts as DHCPD

  - I configured it setting the domain (myCompany.local)
  - To give always the same IP to following machines
- A virtualmachine (Debian BIND9) in my environment (physical host 1)
- Have different client virtual machines lets say vm1, vm2 (Physical host 1)
- My workstation which the only difference I know is it has a wlan0 interface

My ultimate goal is not having to configure the workstations and let the DHCP Server give the domain (myCompany.local) and the IP Address of DNS Server. I read that there are [some practices](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128220/how-do-i-set-my-dns-when-resolv-conf-is-being-overwritten) that don't seem to do like that. So I don't know if

- my approach is wrong
- my configuration is wrong
- I'm wrong
- There is a computer world conspiracy ;-)
- In some machines the network-manager from plasma takes the hand over the other network manager (which I understood is the network `service` which takes `dhclient` with `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` as config file to give requests to the server??!!
- I'm really wrong about all that

Here is my configuration:

### /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost
127.0.1.1       localhost myLptp        myLptp.myCompany.local

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
**strong text**
```

### /etc/network/interfaces

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

### on myLptp /etc/resolv.conf automatically configured by dhclient

```
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

### on vms /etc/resolv.conf automatically configured by dhclient

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search myDomain.local
nameserver 172.16.10.174
```

Comment: You should make sure your interfaces are either being managed by static configuration or NetworkManager only.

Comment: @CameronNemo how do I do that?

Comment: maybe part of the answer is that, on my not working machine `/etc/resolv.conf` is a static file and on the other workings, it is a symlink `/var/run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that part of the answer of my problem was following. I don't know why, but the attributes of the file were changed so that it was immutable.

```
~$ lsattr /etc/resolv.conf
----i---------e---- /etc/resolv.conf
```

When I `sudo chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf` everything came to normal and I could get the first domain and nameserver from DHCP Client

```
~$ lsattr /etc/resolv.conf
--------------e---- /etc/resolv.conf
```