# Adding additional nameservers with resolvconf, dnsmasq & networkmanager

Tags: debian, dns, networkmanager, dnsmasq, resolv.conf

I'm running `resolvconf`, `dnsmasq` and interfaces&connections are managed by `NetworkManager` (nm).

`dnsmasq` is supposed to cache dns entries, and use upstream servers configured via DHCP and manually.

Problem is it seems dnsmasq ends up using upstreams configured *only* via `nm` (using DHCP) - can't figure out how to add manually configured fallbacks (or primaries for that matter).

```
$ cat NetworkManager.conf 
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
rc-manager=resolvconf
# tried also this instead of 'rc-manager': dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=true


$ cat /run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf
nameserver ns-via-dhcp-1
nameserver ns-via-dhcp-2
nameserver ns-via-dhcp-3
nameserver ns-via-dhcp-4
nameserver 127.0.0.1


$ cat /run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf   (think this isn't used anymore as resolvconf pkg is installed?)
# Generated by NetworkManager
search internal.company.domain.co.uk
nameserver ns-via-dhcp-1
nameserver ns-via-dhcp-2
nameserver ns-via-dhcp-3
# NOTE: the libc resolver may not support more than 3 nameservers.
# The nameservers listed below may not be recognized.
nameserver ns-via-dhcp-4


$ cat /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 127.0.0.1
search internal.company.domain.co.uk


$ cat /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 1.1.1.1
```

`/etc/resolv.conf` links to `/etc/resolvconf/run/resolv.conf`, whose contents are same as of `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`.

Note `1.1.1.1` is the custom nameserver I'm trying to add, but seems like `dnsmasq` is not using it. Looking up any domain now takes 2 sec every time, indicating nothing is cached.

`dnsmasq` process w/ params:

```
/usr/sbin/dnsmasq -x /run/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.pid -u dnsmasq -r /run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf -7 /etc/dnsmasq.d,.dpkg-dist,.dpkg-old,.dpkg-new --local-service --trust-anchor=.,20326,8,2,e06d44b80b8f1d39a95c0b0d7c65d08458e880409bbc683457104237c7f8ec8d
```

Also tried adding `server=1.1.1.1` to dnsmasq config, but that didn't work either. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

With the line:
rc-manager=resolvconf

You Network Manager is resorting to using resolvconf, which will pull the settings from your network adapter, alternatively if you do not want to make changes to your network adaptor you can edit your /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base file and add the line:
nameserver 1.1.1.1

For a more detailed answer see the answer here
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128223/191614